# AJAX request is failing because of large JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I having a problem with the following function:

```
function get_request(url){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url
        success: function(response){
            get_request_success(response)
        },
        fail: function(){
            get_request_fail()
        }
    });
```

the server is giving a normal 200 response with the response in the body.

this is the response header (irrelevant data is deleted)
Content-Type: application/json
content-Lenght: 47954
Server: Werkzeug/1.0.0 Python/3.76

if I inspect the browser and I go to network, the data is in the response body. so I think that the Jquery code is too quickly concluding that the request is failing, but I am not sure

errorcode:

```
{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
ParseError
No conversion from text to application/json
```

Comment: whats the exact error that you are getting?

Comment: what does this log?? console.log(response)?

Comment: the get_request_succes function does a simple console.log

Comment: Modifier your response so its small, see if that arrives

Comment: The `fail` method gets the jqXHR object, textStatus, and errorThrown passed in as parameters. Log all three, see what they contain.

Comment: even with a small resonse it not doing what it should do

Comment: I am not having an error, it is just not doing what it supposed to do

Comment: Have your tried specifying "dataType: "json" in your request ? .ajax guesses the return type but it has happened many times where it didn't work until I specifically defined the dataType.

Comment: Looks like your endpoint is responding with invalid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

problem was a server side problem. Because the server was a python application that was ussing pandas it was passing NaN (not a number) values into the JSON respond. JS did not understand this ofcourse. solution was found to run a .fillna("") on the dataframe.